# What is difference between initiate a class and inherit a class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a three classes A, B, and C shown below

```
public class A
{
    public void add(int i, int k)
    {
    }
}
public class B:A
{
    public void AddInt()
    {
        add(1, 2);
    }

}
public class C
{
    public void AddInt()
    {
        A objA = new A();
       objA.add(1, 2);
    }     

}
```

We want access the "A" class method Add, there are two ways

1) Initiate the "A" class, then access the Add method

2) Inherit the "A" class, then access the Add method

If both those ways provide the same functionality, then why does C# provide two ways to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Why it wouldn't provide it?

Comment: You should rethink your examples. A method `Add` that returns void? To address your question... inheritance and instantiatian are completely different concepts and are not provided to achieve the same at all. You inherit from a class to add more functionality without rewriting the entire class, among other things. You instantiate a class to use its functionality.

Comment: @ HighCore iam new to c# so only i ask this ques.

Comment: Do you mean **initiate** or **instantiate**?

Comment: @HighCore I said unknowingly ok leave it ...

Comment: @HighCore: Be nice. Everyone was a beginner once.

Comment: @EricLippert you're right. Im sorry =(

Comment: for a question with a few down votes, it sure does have many answers with many upvotes

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> What is the difference between initiating a class and inheriting a class?

First off, the word you're looking for is **instantiate**, not **initiate**.

> What is the difference between instantiating a class and inheriting a class?

*Inheritance* expresses the "is a kind of" relationship between two classes:

- The New York Times *is a kind of* newspaper.
- A giraffe *is a kind of* animal.
- An apple *is a kind of* fruit.

In each of these cases the first kind of thing is the "more derived" type -- it is *more specific* -- and the second thing is the "less derived" type, or "base" type. It is *more general*. More things are fruits than are apples.

In C# when you establish an inheritance relationship between two classes, you get two things:

- Assignment compatibility: you can use an expression of the more derived type where an expression of the base type is needed.
- Member inheritance: all methods, events, indexers, operators, fields, properties and nested types of the base class are automatically members of the derived class. (Constructors and destructors are not inheritable).

*Instantiation* is the process of making a new instance of a type.

- Here, let me give you a copy of today's New York Times.
- Here, let me give you a giraffe.
- Here, let me give you an apple.

So in C#:

```
class Fruit {}
class Apple : Fruit { } // Apple inherits from Fruit
class Program {
  static void Main() {
    Apple apple = new Apple(); // Instantiating a new Apple
  }
}
```

Make sense?

Comment: You might want to clarify that an inherited class is a _subset_ of the base class' instances, whereas an instantiated class is a _member_ of said set.

Answer (score 8):

It's not about `C#` at all, it's about basic `OOP` concepts, that `C#`, in this case, simply manifests, being [object oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and  [strong typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing) language.

"Initialization" is a creation of an instance of a given type: `A` in your case.

Second example is a [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) , where you derive from a given type `A`, and creating derived type B, is able to access public/protected members of the `A` class.

The access behaviour is the same in **this case**, but origin of that is **completely different**.

Comment: i cant understand pls explain in simply

Comment: @Niventh: in first case you talk about creation of an object and access it's public members. In second case, first you create derived type B, after instantiate it (new B()) and after is able to access A class public Add() method from the instance of B, as it's a *derived type*.

Comment: @Tigran, I downvoted, because Inheritance is not PolyMorphism at all, in fact it used to be said that the three pillars of OOP were Encapsulation, Inheritance, and PolyMorphism. polymorphism is the capability to treat many different things equivalently.  You get PolyMorphism from other things besides Inheritance, in fact it could be argued that it's most ubiquitous and productive source is from using interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

you are comparing Humans with food ... right no comparison

Initiating  cost you some RAM of your system.

Inheriting lets you enable reuseability of common code

Comment: "you are comparing Humans with food ... right no comparison" `public class Cannibal extends Human {...`

Answer (score 3):

These two ways are available because your `add` method is public in class A. Change it to protected if you want to use it only in inherited classes. Simply saying inheritance makes all properties and methods except of private ones available in inherited classes. In your case class `B` is inherited from class `A` and instance of class `B` itself would be your instance to call method `add` on. In class `C` you simply created an instance of class `A` and called method `add` on it. All of this concepts would be much cleaner to you if you'll read about [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Think of a class as a template, or plan, for how to build something.  When you then use the template or plan to build one (think of architect plans for a house, and one of the many houses built from those plans), the words we use to describe this process are "*Instantiation*" and "*Initialization*".

You ***instantiate*** an instance of the object (build the house) using the class template (architects plan), and then ***initialize*** it (paint and decorate the house).

*Inheritance*, on the other hand, refers to something completely unrelated, in how classes are defined, using another existing class as a foundation or ***base***line from which to start the definition of a new class that will *extend* the foundation or *base* class.   When one class inherits from another, it means that "instances" of the derived class automatically get all the stuff that was defined in the parent base class without having to redefine it in the child.

Answer (score 2):

A class is a type and acts as a template that allows you to create objects of this type. The creation of such objects is also called **instantiation**. This instantiation process involves allocating memory for this object (**allocation**) and then initializing this object, i.e. give its fields initial values. The latter is called **initialization**.

**Inheritance** is something completely different. Inheritance is about creating a new class (template) by inheriting existing code from a base class (also called superclass, or parent class).
This new derived class (also called subclass or child class) serves as template for the creation of a new type of objects.

The derived class can modify the behavior inherited from its base class and extend its possibilities. Inheritance creates a relation between the classes. Subclasses are assignment compatible with the superclasses above them in the inheritance hierarchy.